# Pandas: create duplicate rows with certain columns modified

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table like this.

```
A  B1  B2  B3      C
3   1   2   0  'foo'
5   1   4   5  'bar'
7   0   3   0  'baz'
8   0   0   0  'foo'
```

I'd like to create a new data table that looks like this:

```
   A   B     C
 1.5   1 'foo'
 1.5   2 'foo'
1.67   1 'bar'
1.67   4 'bar'
1.67   5 'bar'
   7   3 'baz'
   8   0 'foo'
```

according to the following rules:

1. If none of the `B#` columns is zero, create one new row with `A` unchanged and `B = 0`.
2. If `n >= 1` of the `B#` columns are zero, then create `n` new rows, each with `A` changed to `A/n` and `B` equal to one of the nonzero `B#` columns.

`C` gets left alone. I don't care about the order of the new rows. The actual data table I'm dealing with is tens of megabytes, so if possible, I'd prefer solutions that avoid unnecessary repeated copying.

Answer (score 0):

Here a function that do the stuff:

```
def transform(df):
    """ Iterate over rows of transformed dataframe. """

    for i, r in df.iterrows(): 
        # count number of B# that equal to 0
        n = sum(r[1:3] == 0)  

        if n == 0: 
            yield [r.A, 0, r.C]
        else: 
            yield [r.A/n, r.B1, r.C]
            yield [r.A/n, r.B2, r.C]
            yield [r.A/n, r.B3, r.C]

 new_df = pd.DataFrame(transform(df))
```